# Request.Form throws 'Unexpected end of stream` if Request.Body was read

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

```
if (context.Request.HasFormContentType) { 
    var form = context.Request.Form; // << exception here
}
```

System.IO.IOException: Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component.

How to check Form has null or empty?

Comment: It's suggesting something has already consumed the stream. Is there anything before this code in your class? Also, is this being implemented in middleware, or elsewhere?

Comment: In middleware during invoke